# How to use addListener in useEffect

Tags: react-native

I want to run method when focus screen, i use this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe =  navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log(
        'test'
      );
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

but it doesnt work. it gives an error like this :
*

> An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which
> is used for clean-up. You returned: [object Object]

- 

also even i dont return anything,    console.log(
'test'
) doest work

I am using navigation V4

Comment: This is exactly how it should be. Is this the full code?

Comment: yes it is, it gives that error i really dont understand why.  Console.log never trigger

Answer (score 0):

Is this working?

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
  ......
  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
  ......
   console.log(something)
 }, [something]));

 //-------
```

If not check if react navigation is configured correctly.

UPDATE

In React navigation 4.x you will have to follow one of the methods in this guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/function-after-focusing-screen/

Comment: oh it says: Looks like you are trying to use React Navigation 5 APIs, but have React Navigation 4 installed.  Should i upgrade ? if i do,  can i get errors from other screens ?

Comment: but i use context, how can i do this in context

Answer (score 0):

For `useEffect` to work properly, the flow is following:

- in the square brackets in the end you add a variable which triggers the action. In your case it only triggers on the firs run, and on `navigation` variable change
- you should **run** your function within `useEffect`. You have only defined a constant in the body of `useEffect`, but you never run it.
- optionally you may return a `function` in the end of a run. This function is triggered **only when the component unmounts**, and used to avoid memory leaks.

Based on this: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve (unclear from your original post), but this may be what you want:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log(
        'test'
      );
    });
    
    const unsubscribe = () => navigation.removeListener('focus'); // !!! I'm not sure about this one, check the docs how to unsubscribe !!!

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]); // << triggers useEffect
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest version of react-navigation you must the use-focus-effect.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Your code should be updated as mentioned below

```js
useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(() => {
    const unsubscribe = () => {
      console.log("test");
    }

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [userId])
);
```